# HTML ContentPlaceHolder Content Selected (View Image for more info)

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I've created a site with master page. But whenever user clicked on the Content, there will be a annoying selecting blue line wrapping the whole content pages. Any idea what is it and how should I solved it? Thanks.

```html
Master Page :-
<body>
    <div id="mainPage" data-role="page">
        <header>
            <section>
                <h1 runat="server" id="nandosHeader">PERi-Vilege</h1>
                <div class="wrapperTopNavi">
                    <div class="topNavi">
                     <div class="btnBack left"><a data-rel="back" href="javascript:void(0);"><span></span></a></div>
                        <div class="btnRefresh right"><a href="javascript:void(0);"></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </header>
        <div class="BigWrapper">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <input id="hiddenAppSettings" type="hidden" value="<% =AppSettings %>" />
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </form>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.mobile.document.bind("pageinit", function (event, ui) {
                $('.ui-loader').hide();
            });
        </script>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageScriptContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Screenshot with the annoying selecting blue lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9GTc.png)

```html
Content Page :-
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="BigWrapper">
    <div class="ContentWrapper">
        <h1>Settings</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="btnDivider"></div>
    <div class="ClickDiv" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;">
        <div class="setting">
            <a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Member/Edit.aspx")%>" data-ajax="false">
                <p>Edit Profile</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="arrowright"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="btnDivider"></div>
    <div class="ClickDiv" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;">
        <div class="setting">
            <a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/HowItWorks.aspx") %>" data-ajax="false">
                <p>How it Works</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="arrowright"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="btnDivider"></div>
    <div class="ClickDiv" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;">
        <div class="setting">
            <a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Terms"+ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["loyalty_country"].ToString()+".aspx")%>" data-ajax="false">
                <p>Terms and Conditions</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="arrowright"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="btnDivider"></div>
    <div class="ClickDiv" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;">
        <div class="setting">
            <a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Privacy"+ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["loyalty_country"].ToString()+".aspx")%>" data-ajax="false">
                <p>Personal Data Protection Policy</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="arrowright"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="btnDivider"></div>
    <div class="setting1" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn_logout">
            <p>Log Out</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Provide your code samples or anything useful to further explain your issue

Comment: added in code samples already. The problem is just the highlight blue wrapping all over the content whenever there is any click at the content page.